# Carrierwave upload to Rackspace fails due to Excon error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, rackspace-cloud

I have an application , that uses Carrierwave to upload the pictures on Rackspace. It is absolutely strange the error I get every 20 hours on the production server . It is related with authorization . Here is the log :

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6531ms

Excon::Errors::Unauthorized (Expected(201) <=> Actual(401 Unauthorized)
request => {:connect_timeout=>60, :headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"image/jpeg",
"X-Auth-Token"=>"my-auth-token", "Content-Length"=>439253,
"Host"=>"clouddrive.com:443"}, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :mock=>false, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_limit=>4, :ssl_ca_file=>.....response => #<Excon::Response:0xblah7420 
@body="401 Unauthorized\n\nThis server could not 
verify that you are authorized to        access the document you requested.
 Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), 
or your browser does not understand how to supply the credentials required.\n\n
```

My credentials are Ok , because after restart of Unicorn on the production machine , everything is fine .

I've searched the log messages , but all the things I've found are related to the module Excon , which , it seems , is under development .

I suggest if the restart solves the problem , probably I should make correction on TTL or some setting of my Rackspace ClousFiles .

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yesterday I asked the tech support of Rackspace about my problem and here is the answer:...................................................It is very likely that the application is not coded to check the authentication token expiration date. When using the API authentication provides a token that is valid for 24 hours so that you do not have to re-authenticate on every call. Most applications should be coded such that if it receives an authentication failure, it will re-authenticate to grab the new token. 

How can I handle the authentication failure and avoid daily restart?

Comment: This is a known issue and there is work being done to fix it: https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/1038

Comment: Can you post which version of Carrierwave and Fog you are using?

Comment: Did you manage to fix the problem? I've the same issue too, with Fog 1.9 and carrierwave 0.8

Comment: @shinnyx, I have made a workaround with `whenever` gem , which restarts the Unicorn in production every 23 hours. It works fine , but still it's a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in Fog v1.4. Have you updated your gems recently?

Comment: It seems the bug is still there , my bundle shows v1.4 . I see the v1.5 is here already 12 days , I'll test it. My workaround for now is unicorn restart each 24 h.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I've had other people report that this issue has been resolved.

Comment: I updated to Fog 1.5 and redeployed after having this issue. Fixed it for me.. i'll see if its still working after 24 hours though. could just be the restart of the app that fixed it